Debugging Android applications on Embarcadero RAD Studio 12.1
Question for those who develop an application for Android on Embarcadero RAD Studio 12.1.
Should the debugger work after launching the application on the phone using the Run button (F9) if the application was compiled in the mode:

Build Configuration (Debug)
Target Platforms (Android 64-bit)

The app starts on the phone, but the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint and highlights the breakpoint as unreachable.
Are there any special settings?
USB Debugging is enabled on the phone.
When compiled and launched for the Win32 and Win64 platforms, the debugger works correctly and fully.


Check your firewall. Any Android debugging is made with the help of PAServer with which Delphi si communicating using network connection.  So if your Firewall blocks communication between Delphi and PAServer then Delphi won't receive back any debugging information and thus you won't be able to properly debug your application.

According to the documentation, PAServer for Android is not required and does not exist.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development
No?

This has to be new in Delphi 12. I remember always having problems in Delphi 10 and Delphi 11 if I had not allowed network traffic between Delphi and PAServer.

There is no PAServer in Android debugging

This behavior is not exclusive to Android. Try deleting the Android64 folder in your Applications folder. Use the "Clean" option from the context menu of your "Project1". After that, use "Build" and then run the debugger. In most cases, this helps resolve my debugging problems.
It looks like this is a new "feature" of Delphi 12 ;-)
Edit: This was a proper Solution till now. since Delphi 12.1 there maybe is another Problem with that. Still looking into it, will keep this post updated.

Unfortunately, this didn't help me.
I tried running the Project-Clean command.
Delete the Android64 folder.
Create a new empty project.
Breakpoints are not available in project sources.

Oh, thats strange. Do you have the Patch installed for Delphi 12.1? What Android version do you use? Do you have installed the "Android SDK 25.2.5 - NDK r21" and "Eclipse Temurion OpenJDK 17 (Hotspot) JVM" under Tools --> Features?

I use RAD Studio 12 Version 29.0.51961.7529 (Update 1).
"Android SDK 25.2.5 - NDK r21" and "Eclipse Temurion OpenJDK 17 (Hotspot) JVM" - Yes ,It is installed.

I did not install Patch 1 for Delphi 12.1.
They wrote that This patch addresses some issues in RAD Studio 12.1, around the new editor split view feature of the IDE.

Are you able to connect to the log.d via https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/DeviceLens. ? What's the Settings under Project Debugging. Is Full Debugging enabled? Is DCU debugging selected?

I installed the Device Lens 2.1.0 program but I don’t understand what exactly to look at in it. The Start command begins writing hundreds of messages per second to the table.
I use all default settings. In the Compiling-Debuging settings Debug Information = Debug Information, Use debug .dcus = Checked.

The following information was posted on the website https://discourse.embarcadero.com/,

markus.humm, Embarcadero MVP,
There was something regarding startup times and the debugger in 12.1 I think. Not sure if yours is related, but might be worth to reread what was discussed back then. I think there was something mentioned in the What’s new documentation in 12.1 Beta. Not sure if you have access to that material.

Device lense was just to check if you are able to get Informations from your mobile Device. Also the adb seams to work. Unfortunately I have no access to your link. Do you have a chance to test another android device? I work with Android and Delphi 12.1 on dayli basis. No problem with the debugger so far that was not resolved by cleaning and rebuilding the Project.

I was able to get the debugger to stop at breakpoints a couple of times. But this happens once out of thirty launches. I can't understand the pattern. I didn't change the settings.

This problem does not depend much on the device. I have tried several phones and tablets.

As Mentioned before. I know this behavior as well. I could fix it every Time if I do the Steps in my Answer one after each other. Delete Android64 Folder --> do CleanUp --> Create --> Run debug

@DmitryB - Can you do me a favor? Yesterday, I stumbled upon the same behavior and was not able to solve it either. Could you please check if you get an Access Violation when you start your application as Win32 with the debugger?

I don't have any debugger errors related to the Win32, Win64, or Linux64 platforms.
The problem is only with the Android32, Android64 platform.
